# composer update --no-dev made website super slow

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Im new to Magento 2.3,

first I had an issue installing anything through composer because it was saying that my php 7.3 doesnt meet requirements which is 7.1 or 7.2. My php actually 7.1, so I don't know how it was reading 7.3, anyways I went and edit composer.json and added:

```
"platform": {
             "php": "7.1.25"
    },
```

That helped and I was able to install all applications that require composer. After I went to extension manager and decided to install another application through marketplace and got a Readiness Red mark about dependencies issue, obviously because I edit my composer file. So somewhere I read that I should do

> composer update --no-dev

, I know stupid and even though after I did

> composer update

and everything was installed again, my website became super slow, can't open extension manager anymore. Please help me fix it.